# What size meter socket

Tags: electrical, meter

I am putting new 100 amp service to my garage. Do I use only 100 amp meter socket or can I use  a 125 amp

Comment: I take it your garage is getting a completely separate service from the utility then?  Who is your utility, for that matter?

Comment: As your power utility if they have a list of approved meter sockets, that may eliminate a choice.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason why you cannot install a larger meter base than the one required. Keep in mind that equipment is rated to handle maximum currents not minimum. In your case a 100A meter base can only handle current up to 100A. Whereas a 125A handles up to 125A and will handle a 100A current without a problem.

Her's an idea. When I was working we always installed a 200A meter base since know you have the ability to upgrade a service if needed later, and comparing material cost the upgrade was minimal and labor is more or less the same. The only reason we would install a smaller base would be because of space restrictions.

Good luck

Comment: In our area, the utility has an approved list of meter sockets.  Currently the smallest on the list is 200amp, and it gets a 200 amp drop.

Comment: I agree with 3phase, but as Tyson said many utilities have a minimum and for new services they usually provide a web site with the utility requirements that may be much different than the NEC requirements.+